# 量子コンピュータが通信系(とくに ssl, aka https) に与える影響は?

Tags: https, 暗号理論, 量子コンピュータ

量子コンピュータのスタートアップが立ち上がるなどしていて、この分野が最近ホットそうだ、と思っています。量子コンピュータは、電子回路を用いた演算とは実行できる計算が異なるので、これまで計算量的に取り扱えなかった問題が解けるようになると理解しています。

特に、計算量的困難さによって秘匿性を実現している、暗号系の分野において一番影響がありそうだな、と思っています。特に、それを基盤に用いているもろもろのセキュア通信に対する影響度合いは高いのではないか、と思っています。

#### 質問

- 量子コンピュータのコストあたりの性能が、ムーアの法則的に向上していったとして、それは既存の通信系、にどれぐらいの影響を及ぼしますか? (e.g. まったく安全性がなくなってしまう、など) たとえば、広く普及しているセキュア通信は https ですが、これは量子コンピュータの発展により秘匿性は破られてしまいますか?

#### 追記

量子コンピュータには、おおまかにいって汎用計算機の、いわゆる「古典的量子コンピュータ」と、最近発展してきている、やきなまし法を実行するのに特化した「量子アニーリングマシン」がある様子です。どちらかというと、「古典的量子コンピュータ」の方を想定していました。計算量的に定義しなおすと:

- 量子コンピュータが多項式時間で解ける問題に、 ssl の鍵の推定は含まれますか?

Comment: 個人的に、「オフトピック」ではないと思うので、メタ投稿しています。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2637/754

Comment: 自分もオフトピックではないと考えます。つい先日、レポートが公開されていてお役に立つかもしれません。http://www.imes.boj.or.jp/research/abstracts/japanese/18-J-02.html

Comment: ^*2 メタで議論した結果、「オフトピックではない」となったので再オープンしています。

Comment: ただ、それをモデレータの一票で行うのは違う、ということなので、再度クローズしました。

Answer (score 2):

そもそも量子コンピュータが実用化(個人が所有できる程度)される技術水準になれば、量子通信も完成しているはずです。このため、量子コンピュータによって暗号化が破られたとしても、量子通信によって通信の完全性/機密性が保たれると思います。部分的な通信データはタップされると思いますけどね。

Answer (score 2):

今までの暗号化方式ではセキュアではなくなると思います。
WiFiでいうWEPは危険なのでWPA2を使いましょう、と同じ問題ではないでしょうか(WPA2にも脆弱性があったようですが…)。

最近NICTが新しい暗号方式を発表していましたので、こういった量子コンピュータでも解読されないような暗号化方式が主流になっていくのだと思います。
https://www.nict.go.jp/press/2018/01/11-1.html